# How to poulate the spinner at run time?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I do not know what is wrong , All I wanted to do is to populate the Spinner at run time. But When I run my app on mobile it is populating the spinner with my path of class. Here is a code what I am doing

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner spSelectTeam;
    TextView tvTeam;
    ArrayList<TeamClass> teamClasses;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
        init();
        teamClasses = populateList();
        //applying adapter
        ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, teamClasses);
        spSelectTeam.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

    void init(){
        spSelectTeam = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_team);
        tvTeam = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_team);
    }

    public ArrayList<TeamClass> populateList() {
        //ArrayList<TeamClass> myTeamName = new ArrayList<TeamClass>();
        ArrayList<TeamClass> teamClasses = new ArrayList<>();
        teamClasses.add(new TeamClass("----- All -----"));
        teamClasses.add(new TeamClass("Computer Direct"));
        teamClasses.add(new TeamClass("Datasys"));
        teamClasses.add(new TeamClass("Host Interactive"));
        return teamClasses;
    }
}
```

and the class for the adapter is

```
public class TeamClass {
    private String TeamName;

    public TeamClass(String teamName){
        this.TeamName = teamName;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return TeamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        TeamName = teamName;
    }
}
```

please help . thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override `toString()` for the `TeamClass` .

Comment: Thanks this method helps me .

Comment: how to change the color of text in that spinner ? its white I want to change to black

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
        init();
        teamClasses = populateList();

        //applying adapter

        ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, teamClasses);
myAdapter .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

 spSelectTeam.setAdapter(myAdapter);



    }
```

Comment: But (s)he also needs to extend `BaseAdapter` class so that he can provide his custom layout, though in this case he can just override `toString()` method like barq suggested

Answer (score 1):

add in your `TeamClass`

```
 @Override
 public String toString() {
    return this.TeamName ;
}
```

also change your code with below like..

```
List<TeamClass> teamClasses;

teamClasses = populateList();

public List<TeamClass> populateList() {
    List<TeamClass> teamClasses = new ArrayList<TeamClass>();
    teamClasses.add(new TeamClass("----- All -----"));
    teamClasses.add(new TeamClass("Computer Direct"));
    teamClasses.add(new TeamClass("Datasys"));
    teamClasses.add(new TeamClass("Host Interactive"));
    return teamClasses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following to your TeamClass:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getTeamName();
}
```